# Android database more than 1MB

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written database copy.I have put my database into asset forder.My db size is 4.5 MB.
How to chunk the databse.

```
    package com.xont.db;

  public class DataBaseMasterHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.xont.controller/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "masterventura.db";
private SQLiteDatabase ventura;
private  Context myContext;
private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;

public DataBaseMasterHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 **/
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        //this.getReadableDatabase().getPath();
        System.out.println( " ===== " +     this.getReadableDatabase().getPath());
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();


}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    ventura = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (ventura != null)
        super.close();
        ventura.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

}

In the copyDataBase() method i need to change the code.How can I split the database.Please help me on this

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The only way I see is that in `copyDataBase()` method you open your database and manipulate data with SQL statements. After that you can close it and copy to sdcard. Database size could be chunked by throwing out usless garbage (open database and iterfere with SQL statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post that is exactly what you are looking for:

http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2010/mar/13/deploying-android-apps-with-large-databases/

Comment: The Link did not work for me, so I found an archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20150119010602/http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2010/mar/13/deploying-android-apps-with-large-databases/